# Inheritance - change variable upon initialization based on child value

Tags: c#, inheritance, xna

I have one base class:

```
class Tile{}
```

And few others which extends tile

```
class Free : Tile{}
class Wall : Tile{}
```

Each tile have its own texture, it isn't string but its Texture2D which has to be loaded upon initialization. I imagine code will look similar to this but I'm not sure how to create this properly:

```
class Tile{
    static Texture2D texture; //Static will use less ram because it will be same for inherited class?
    static string texture_path; //This is set by inherited class
    public Tile(){
        if(texture==null)
            texture = LoadTexture(texture_path);
    }
}

class Free : Tile{
    static string texture_path = "Content/wall.png";
}
```

With other words, all Free tiles have same texture and all Wall tiles have same textures - that is why in my opinion I should use static.

How to do this properly?

Comment: What's your question? Questions generally have a question mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is declare the property in base class and provide an option for the  child class to override it. This will allow you to also provide a default value if you want to.

Some thing like this:

```
public class Tile
{
    private string _texturePath = String.Empty;
    private Texture2D _texture;
    protected virtual string TexturePath { private get { return _texturePath; } set { _texturePath = value; } }

    public Tile()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TexturePath))
            _texture = LoadTexture(TexturePath);
    }
    private Texture2D LoadTexture(string texturePath)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

internal class Texture2D
{
}

public sealed class Free:Tile
{
    protected override string TexturePath
    {
        set
        {
            if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
            base.TexturePath = "Content/wall.png";
        }
    }
}
```

In case you do not want to provide a default texture path, you can plan to make the property and the base class abstract.

Comment: Will Texture2D load for every new initialized Free:tile?

Comment: Yes in this case. In case you want the texture for free class loads only once and all Free objects share that texture instance, then the implementation has to be changed slightly by allowing texture 2d property to be moved to child class and providing a factory which returns a singelton of Texture based on which Tile implementation is requesting the object

Answer (score 0):

If you want your base class to have access to texture_path you should declare it in your base class.

A baseclass doesn't know anything about fields, properties or methods declared in its subclasses. This is by design BTW...

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you want all instances of `Free` to share a texture and all instances of `Wall` to share a texture. This means that you want the `static` fields `texture` and `texture_path` to be in the child classes, not the parent.

Ex:

```
public class Tile { }

public class Free : Tile
{
    private static Texture2D texture;
    private static string texture_path;
}

public class Wall : Tile
{
    private static Texture2D texture;
    private static string texture_path;
}
```

If you want `Tile` references to have `texture` and `texture_path` properties so that you can access the shared `texture` or `texture_path` from an instance, you need a `virtual` or `abstract` property.

Ex:

```
public abstract class Tile
{
    public abstract Texture2D Texture { get; }
    public abstract string TexturePath { get; }
}

public class Free : Tile
{
   private static Texture2D texture;
   private static string texture_path;

   public override Texture2D Texture { get { return texture; } }
   public override string TexturePath { get { return texture_path; } }
}

// and similarly for Wall
```